# Spring Integration using DSL for reading file from Unix location

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a requirement where i need to look for a file continuously at unix location.Once its available then i need to parse it and convert to some json format.This needs to be done using Spring integration - DSL.
Following is the piece of code I got from spring site but it shows following exception:

```
o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.processFileChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
```

Below is the code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FileReadingJavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(FileReadingJavaApplication.class)
            .web(false)
            .run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fileReadingFlow() {
         return IntegrationFlows
                  .from(s -> s.file(new File("Y://"))
                              .patternFilter("*.txt"),
                          e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)))
                  .transform(Transformers.fileToString())
                  .channel("processFileChannel")
                  .get();
        }

}
```

New Code:

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringIntegration {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringIntegration.class)
    .web(false)
    .run(args);
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost("ip");
    factory.setPort(port);
    factory.setUser("username");
    factory.setPassword("pwd");
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
}

@Bean
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("remote dir");
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.txt"));

    return fileSynchronizer;
}
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
public MessageSource ftpMessageSource() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
            new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
    source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File("Local directory"));

    return source;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    return new MessageHandler() {


        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            System.out.println("File Name : "+message.getPayload());

        }

    };
}
```

@Bean
        public static StandardIntegrationFlow processFileFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlows
                    .from("fileInputChannel").split()
                    .handle("fileProcessor", "process").get();

```
    }

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fileInputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
public MessageSource<File> fileReadingMessageSource() {
    AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File> filters =new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>();

    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    source.setDirectory(new File("Local directory"));
    source.setFilter(filters);

    return source;
}
@Bean
public FileProcessor fileProcessor() {
    return new FileProcessor();
}


 @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fileInputChannel")
    public AmqpOutboundEndpoint amqpOutbound(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
        AmqpOutboundEndpoint outbound = new AmqpOutboundEndpoint(amqpTemplate);
        outbound.setExpectReply(true);
        outbound.setRoutingKey("foo"); // default exchange - route to queue 'foo'
        return outbound;
    }



    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "amqpOutboundChannel")
    public interface MyGateway {
        String sendToRabbit(String data);

    }
```

}

FileProcessor:

public class FileProcessor {

```
public void process(Message<String> msg) {
    String content = msg.getPayload();
    JSONObject jsonObject ;
    Map<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(int i=0;i<=content.length();i++){
    String userId = content.substring(i+5,i+16);


    dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    dataMap.put("username", username.trim());


    i+=290; //each record of size 290 in file
     jsonObject = new JSONObject(dataMap);
    System.out.println(jsonObject);

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct , but an exception tells you that there is need something what will read messages from the direct channel "processFileChannel".

Please, read more about different channel types in the [Spring Integration Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html).

**EDIT**

One of first class citizen in Spring Integration is `MessageChannel` abstraction. See [EIP](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageChannel.html) for more information.

The definition like `.channel("processFileChannel")` mean declare [`DirectChannel`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#channels). This kind of channel means accept message on the send and perform handling *directly* just in `send` process. In the raw Java words it may sound like: call one service from another. Throw `NPE` if the another hasn't been autowired.

So, if you use `DirectChannel` for the output, you should declare somewhere a *subscriber* for it. I don't know what is your logic, but that is how it works and no other choice to fix `Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel`.

Although you can use some other `MessageChannel` type. But for this purpose you should read more doc, e.g. Mark Fisher's [Spring Integration in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/spring-integration-in-action).

Comment: Actually I am new to Spring Integration.The concept being a bit tricky it will be helpful if you can tell me the changes i need to do according to my requirement.

Comment: All you are doing is sending the contents of the file to "processFileChannel" - but you need something to consume that data - some other flow that starts with the channel.

Comment: Please, find an `EDIT` in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I have been able to connect to unix .however , now i want the file data to be converted to json and inserted in queue.However the exception is :Circular reference involving containing bean SpringIntegration- consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'amqpOutbound' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.integration.mapping.AbstractHeaderMapper: method <init>()V not found